# File I/O Error. Not Load

Tags: c++, file-io

```
LoginId.open("../../bin/Data/JoinID.txt", ios::in);
if (!LoginId.is_open())
    printf("Load Fail\n");
```

This Code is compile. 
visual studio 2015 good action. debug mode action File. 
but (.exe)file action can not File Load.

The bin folder contain (.exe) File and Data folder.
Data folder contain in the JoinID.txt.

why (.exe)file action can not load JoinID.txt??

Comment: Try using an *absolute* path instead. Relative paths depends on the processes current working directory, and it might not be what you expect it to be.

Comment: solution! Sorry...

Comment: What does `std::cerr << "Error: " << strerror(errno);` outputs for you? (put it right after `open`